# How to sort a large text file into a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to read a large text file and sort it into a 3D array using scanner() but I don't think the array is being populated, and I keep getting the error `java.lang.NullPointerException`, but I suspect there is more going wrong than just that.

I'm currently trying to use nested for loops to sort out the year, month, and each date.

Another thing that I'd like to do is change the array from `String` to `int` but it's having none of it.

Here is my code:

```
public class GetData {

    public String[][][] sortedData;

    private Scanner rainFile;

    //method for opening the file
    public void openFile() {

        try{
            rainFile = new Scanner(new File("myfile.txt"));
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Could not find file");
        }
    }

    //method for reading the file
    public void readFile(){

        int month = 0;
        int day = 0;

        //this loop sorts each year
        for(int l = 0; l < 34; l++){
            String a = rainFile.next();
            sortedData[l][month][day] = a;

                //this loop sorts every month of each year
                for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
                    String b = rainFile.next();
                    sortedData[l][i][day] = b;
                    month++;

                        //this loop sorts each individual entry of every month
                        for(int j = 0; j < 31; j++){
                            String c = rainFile.next();
                            sortedData[l][i][j] = c;
                            day++;
                        }
                    }        
                }

        }

        //close the file once it's been used
        public void closeFile(){
            rainFile.close();
        }

        //test method to see if array is full
        public void arrayTest(){
            System.out.print(sortedData[1][1][1]);
        }
}
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create instance first

```
public String[][][] sortedData = new String[n][n2][n3]; //n1 n2 n3 dimension size
```

Comment: If I have 34 years, 408 months, and 12648 days would it be `public String[][][] sortedData = new String[34][408][12648];` or `public String[][][] sortedData = new String[34][12][31];`? The former just seems excessive for some reason.

Edit: the former worked, thank you so much!

Comment: No you need [34][12][31]. then your array will have 34 * 12 * 31 elements.
Each of 34 years will contain 12 month, and each month will contain 31 day

Comment: I just changed it to [34][12][31] and got an exception again. I thought that multi-dimensional arrays in Java weren't true multi-dimensional arrays?

Comment: @JoshJahans that's because you use variable day as index.

Comment: What should I use instead?

Comment: it depends what you expect in array

Answer (score 1):

You forgot this:

```
sortedData = new String[34][12][31];
```